# Adding layers and visualizing data simultaneously from both

Tags: carto

I am having a trouble showing data from a second level.

For example, I have joined my two data sets with matching row: Community districts in NYC.
The first layer has a thematically shaded map of jail population per community district. 
I want to then add a layer of proportional dots on top of this existing layer that references another column (i.e. % spanish speaking)

How can I add the second layer and not take away the bottom thematic shading.

Comment: Could you maybe add a screenshot or detail more how your data is structured? It seems you have a polygon layer of districts and another point layer on top of that?

Comment: Yes I have a polygon layer of districts and then I have jail population data shaded on top of that. I am looking to then use another column of my dataset (related to languages spoken) and layer that on top of the rest (using a different visualization style)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BUILDER auto style](https://carto.com/learn/guides/widgets/auto-style-to-view-dynamic-data) in order to **show two (or more) layer variables/dimensions/columns in the same visualization:**

- First, go to WIDGETS tab and click on ADD WIDGET.
- Secondly, select "Histogram" and check your two numeric variables, making sure you are selecting the right layer analysis node.
- Third, click on ADD WIDGET.

Now, **with a single click on the auto style button (located directly from an embedded widget) applies a temporary color scheme**, lets you filter by those two selected columns, and styles the map, as shown in the following screenshot from [this blog post](https://carto.com/blog/data-driven-maps-auto-style).

[image: auto-style1]

Answer (score 0):

Another, more "classic" approach would be generating a point layer and visualizing it on top of your polygon layer. To do so:

1. Run a *Find Centroid of Geometries* analysis on your polygon layer. The result will be a points layer (your polygon layer will seem to have disappeared).
2. Drag out the *Join* node to create a new layer with your polygons joined to your data.
3. Style the points layer to your liking (by size, shape, etc).

Here's an example showing the process of dragging out a node:

[image: Dragging out node after centroid analysis]